# Video player problems in Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I was building a app involving a video player, i have a list view which displays a list of videos and clicking on any of those should play that video. The links i use are rstp youtube links & the video plays fine but when i click back button after the video is played & come to the list again i get Sorry video cant be played error.

Here is my video player class & the list Class:

Video Player class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);
    vid=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.svid);
    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.simg);
    ip=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playimg);
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(SingleItem.this);
    Intent g=getIntent();
    thumb=g.getStringExtra("thumb");
    link=g.getStringExtra("link");
    msg=g.getStringExtra("msg");
    //link="rtsp://v7.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQmgwjdV-8ZI5BMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBWluZGV4YKSf0bH1u4jEUAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";
     String path1=link;
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(vid);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(vid);
        uri=Uri.parse(path1);
        vid.setMediaController(mc);
        vid.setVideoURI(uri);
      //  vid.requestFocus();
        //iv.setClickable(true);
        loadImage(thumb);
        t.setText(msg);
        ip.setClickable(true);
        ip.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        // ip.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        vid.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //ip.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                pd.dismiss();

            }
        });
        ip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 vid.start();
                 pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    pd.setMessage("Loading Video...");
                    pd.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pd.setCancelable(true);
                    pd.show();

                    if(vid.isPlaying()){
                         iv.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                         ip.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                     }else{
                         iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                         ip.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                         vid.stopPlayback();
                     }

            }
        });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    vid.stopPlayback();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    vid.stopPlayback();
}

void loadImage(String image_location){

    URL imageURL = null;

    try {
     imageURL = new URL(image_location);
     } 

    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

    try {
     HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//Convert to bitmap
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

My List class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pf=new PrefMethods(this);
    e=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    go=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bGo);


    e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getText().length()==0){
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(VideoList.this, myList);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here finally", 500).show();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        arr_link = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr_thumb = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr_msg = new ArrayList<String>();
        allItems=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            URL urlnew= new URL("link");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpURLConnection) urlnew.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
                        // gets the server json data
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String next;
            while ((next = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(next);
                int k=ja.length();
                vid_id=pf.loadprefs();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here", 500).show();
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    WaveData waveData = new WaveData(jo.getString("VUpload"), jo.getInt("recid"),jo.getString("VYoutube"),jo.getString("VMessage"),jo.getString("VThumb"));
                    if(jo.getInt("recid")>vid_id){
                        if(i==k-1){
                            pf.saveprefs(jo.getInt("recid")); 
                            //vid_id=2;
                            vid_id=jo.getInt("recid");
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+vid_id, 500).show();
                        }else{}
                    }else{}
                    if(jo.has("VUpload")){
                    map.put("msg", jo.getString("VMessage"));
                    map.put("youtube", jo.getString("VYoutube"));
                    map.put("thumb", jo.getString("VThumb"));
                  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here too", 500).show();
                    myList.add(map);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jo.getString("VMessage"), 500).show();
                    items.add(jo.getString("VMessage"));
                    arr_msg.add(jo.getString("VMessage"));
                    arr_link.add(jo.getString("VYoutube"));
                    arr_thumb.add(jo.getString("VThumb"));
                    }       
                }     
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, myList);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here finally", 500).show();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set List ", 500).show();
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String l=list.getAdapter().getItem(arg2).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), l, 500).show();
                String sthumb=arr_thumb.get(arg2);
                String slink=arr_link.get(arg2);
                String smsg=arr_msg.get(arg2);
                Intent vid=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleItem.class);
                vid.putExtra("link", slink);
                vid.putExtra("msg", smsg);
                vid.putExtra("thumb", sthumb);
                startActivity(vid); 
            }
        });

          go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                allItems.clear();
                String l= e.getText().toString();
                for(int g=0;g<vid_id;g++){

                    if(myList.get(g).containsValue(l)){
                        allItems.add(myList.get(g));
                    }
                }
                adapter=new LazyAdapter(VideoList.this, allItems);
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here finally", 500).show();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The video list gets loaded no issues & even the video plays but when i click the back button it comes back to list & says Sorry,this video cant be played !

Any ideas why the error?

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue, all i did was made the video stop playing in the onPause & onDestroy method.

Now it works fine without any error